# Creating an Attribute to check for Exceptions

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm creating an attribute so that whenever an exception occurs on my site, I'll receive an email detailing the exception. I've got so far but my Attribute code doesn't seem to fire if an exception occurs:

```
public class ReportingAttribute : FilterAttribute, IExceptionFilter
{
    public void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {
        // This will generate an email to me
        ErrorReporting.GenerateEmail(filterContext.Exception);
    }
}
```

Then above my Controller I'm doing:

```
[ReportingAttribute]
public class AccountController : Controller
```

The other way to do it is ofcourse putting `ErrorReporting.GenerateEmail(ex)` inside my catch blocks? There must be a simpler way? Thats why I thought of creating the Attribute to handle this

Comment: Isn't `IExceptionFilter.OnException()` only invoked on unhandled exceptions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the purpose of logging all uncaught exceptions, you can define the following method in your `Global.asax.cs` file:

```
private void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        //
        // Try to be as "defensive" as possible, to ensure gathering of max. amount of info.
        //

        HttpApplication app = (HttpApplication) sender;

        if(null != app.Context)
        {
            HttpContext context = app.Context;

            if(null != context.AllErrors)
            {
                foreach(Exception ex in context.AllErrors)
                {
                    // Log the **ex** or send it via mail.
                }
            }

            context.ClearError();
            context.Server.Transfer("~/YourErrorPage");
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.StatusCode = (int) HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
        HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
    }
}
```

Comment: Well I want to mail all exceptions, whether I've caught them or not

Comment: If you catch an exception and not rethrow it, wouldn't that mean that application can proceed normally? And if it can, why do you need to mail the exception? In the rare cases when you do need it, you can just manually write a line of code in the `catch` block. And all the uncaught (or rethrown) exceptions will be mailed to you automatically.

Comment: Well I'll give you an example: My app depends heavily on my webservice, if for whatever reason this goes down, I need to log the user out and tell them an error has occured. This works fine, but as an extra feature I'd like to get an email that there is a problem so I can try to fix it early, now I have a try/catch around my methods to catch for this exception but instead of manually writing this code into each catch block, I thought it'd be nicer to just create an attribute or something

Comment: First of all, I don't think there are **any** means for reacting to **unhandled** exceptions. Second of all, you can also implement the logging out logic in one place - `Application_Error()`, as I suggested. So just follow a generic rule - do not swallow exceptions from which you cannot recover. Let them bubble up to `Application_Error()` and let it do the generic handling for such exceptions.

Comment: I've taken your advice and put my code in to my catch block, then for unhandled exceptions im using the application_error message, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`Attribute` just by itself *can not* define a behaviour, but its used for make some marks over your code data. You should write a code, where you

- get an exception
- check for given attribute presence in the method that raised an exception
- if it is present, collect and send the data you need.

Answer (score 0):

Why not create an base controller:

```
public ApplicationBaseController : Controller
{
    public override void OnException(ExceptionContext context)
    {
        //Send your e-mail
    }
}
```

And derive your controller from `ApplicationBaseController`

```
public HomeController : ApplicationBaseController
{
    //.....
}
```

Comment: I tried this but I didnt get any email when an exception occurred

Comment: Are you sure your e-mail settings configured the right way? Notice that this method only is invoked on **unhandled exceptions**